# proofs involving congruence of integers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let n, m be integers. Prove that if n ≡ 1( mod 2) and m ≡ 3( mod 4), then n^2 +m ≡ 0(mod4)

My thought process is  that n=3 and m=7 so n^2 would be 9+7 but then i do not believe that would equal 0(mod4) which i think would equal 4.

Any direction would help on where to start or how to attack this problem.

Comment: Note that $4\equiv 0\pmod 4$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Consider two cases:

$n\equiv 1\text{mod}4$

or

$n\equiv 3\text{mod}4$

What can you say about $n^2\text{mod}4$ in either of those cases?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that since it is squared it would be even

Comment: @Cole If $n\equiv 1\text{mod}2$ then $n$ is odd.  If $n\equiv 1\text{mod}2$ then either $n\equiv 1\text{mod}4$ or $n\equiv 3\text{mod}4$.  An odd number squared is always odd.  Why would you think it would be even?

Comment: Ya you are right sorry. it's been a really long day. I screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

$n \equiv 1( \mod 2)$ means $\exists a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n = 2\cdot a + 1$, so 
$$ n^2 = (2\cdot a + 1)^2 = 4a^2 + 4a +1.$$

So you can calculate $n^2 +m \mod 4$ now.